# How to rob / kill workers in Mafia Wars 2?

Tags: mafia-wars-2

I can rob the building but can't rob workers and prostitutes...

How can I achieve this because it's a mission that I have to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only rob workers if they are available to be 'harvested'. Just think in terms of your own workers. Most of the time, they have a timer on them indicating when they will be available to collect money from. If your opponent's workers are in this state, then they cannot be robbed. When timer counts down to zero, this is when you can collect money from them, this is also when they are vulnerable to robbery. Same applies to your opponent's workers.

Therefore, if your opponent is extremely active, it leaves a very small window of opportunity for you to rob their workers, as it's more likely they'll have collected the money from their workers before you have the opportunity to rob. Is this clear to you?

It's really a matter of luck actually. There are two ways to do this. 1) Randomly pick an opponent and check to see if any of their workers is ready to rob. Keep repeating the process. Or 2) You can camp by marking a specific opponent (preferably one with many workers), and keep going back to him/her every now and then to check for valid targets. To mark an opponent, click on the **rivals** icon a the bottom of your game window, which will give you a list of opponents you've had contact with, click on your target and choose **mark**.